# Changing size ("Crouching" Function)

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine

I'm using an idea of shrinking the player and resizing them to normal on a key bind toggle (Press "e" go small, press "e" to go back to normal). Unfortunately I've ran into a problem where when pressing the key bind, it will do both in quick succession, allowing no size change. If anyone has any insight into how I can fix this, let me know

(Script provided below, look for "Shrink" for problem area)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class ThirdPersonMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
public CharacterController controller;
public Transform cam;
public Transform groundCheck;

private Vector3 originalCenter;
private float originalHeight;
private float originalMoveSpeed;
private bool shrink;

public float speed = 10f;
public float gravity = -9.81f;
public float groundDistance = 0.4f;
public float jumpHeight = 3f;
public LayerMask groundMask;

Vector3 velocity;
bool isGrounded;

public float turnSmoothTime = 0.1f;
float turnSmoothVelocity;

void Start()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;

    transform.tag = "Player";
    controller = GetComponent<CharacterController>();   
    originalCenter = controller.center;
    originalHeight = controller.height;
    originalMoveSpeed = speed; 
}

void Update()
{
    isGrounded = Physics.CheckSphere(groundCheck.position, groundDistance, groundMask);

    if(isGrounded && velocity.y < 0)
    {
        velocity.y = -2f;
    }

    float horizontal = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    float vertical = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");
    Vector3 direction = new Vector3(horizontal, 0f, vertical).normalized;

    velocity.y += gravity * Time.deltaTime;
    controller.Move(velocity * Time.deltaTime);

    if(Input.GetButton("Shrink") && shrink == false)
    {
        controller.height = 1f;
        controller.center = new Vector3(0f, -0.36f, 0f);
        speed = 3f;
        shrink = true;
        Debug.Log ("Small");
    }
    if(Input.GetButton("Shrink") && shrink == true)
    {
        controller.height = originalHeight;
        controller.center = originalCenter;
        speed = originalMoveSpeed;
        shrink = false;
        Debug.Log ("Normal");
    }

    if(Input.GetButtonDown("Jump") && isGrounded)
    {
        velocity.y = Mathf.Sqrt(jumpHeight * -2f * gravity);
    }

    if (direction.magnitude >= 0.1f)
    {
        float targetAngle = Mathf.Atan2(direction.x, direction.z) * Mathf.Rad2Deg + cam.eulerAngles.y;
        float angle = Mathf.SmoothDampAngle(transform.eulerAngles.y, targetAngle, ref turnSmoothVelocity, turnSmoothTime);
        transform.rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0f, angle, 0f);

        Vector3 moveDir = Quaternion.Euler(0f, targetAngle, 0f) * Vector3.forward;
        controller.Move(moveDir.normalized * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leandro's answer is a good start. In addition to his, I'd change the `Input.GetButton` to `Input.GetButtonDown` so the call is made only once per key press.

```
if(Input.GetButtonDown("Shrink") && shrink == false)
{
    controller.height = 1f;
    controller.center = new Vector3(0f, -0.36f, 0f);
    speed = 3f;
    shrink = true;
    Debug.Log ("Small");
}
else if(Input.GetButtonDown("Shrink") && shrink == true)
{
    controller.height = originalHeight;
    controller.center = originalCenter;
    speed = originalMoveSpeed;
    shrink = false;
    Debug.Log ("Normal");
}
```

Comment: I'll make this the best answer since it expands on the original answer, appreciate the help friend

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 1):

Missing an `else` on the second `if`, the way it is both `if`'s are always tested and by the time the code runs the `if(Input.GetButton("Shrink") && shrink == true)` test, `shrink` is actually `true`.

Try this:

```
if(Input.GetButton("Shrink") && shrink == false)
{
    controller.height = 1f;
    controller.center = new Vector3(0f, -0.36f, 0f);
    speed = 3f;
    shrink = true;
    Debug.Log ("Small");
}
else if(Input.GetButton("Shrink") && shrink == true)
{
    controller.height = originalHeight;
    controller.center = originalCenter;
    speed = originalMoveSpeed;
    shrink = false;
    Debug.Log ("Normal");
}
```

Comment: That did it, and I learned a valuable lesson on it too, for something to be so simple. Thank you very much. And Rökkr did expand upon your solution, to make it more efficient, which is why I marked him as Best Answer. Again, I appreciate the help.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad I could help!